# How to bind data with ngFor in angular

Tags: html, angular, data-binding, datatable, tr

I am new to angular. Just learning it.
I want to bind data with ngFor. but its not showing any data. Kindly help me to solve this

html file :

```
 <tbody class="text-center">
          <tr *ngFor="let agent of agentlist ;let i = index">
              <td>{{i + 1 + paginationObject?.page * paginationObject?.itemPerPage}}</td>-->
              <td>{{agent?.id?agent?.id:''}}</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
```

error : `<!--bindings={   "ng-reflect-ng-for-of": null }-->`

Comment: Did you tried removing the '-->' at the end of the first Table Cell?, Also you have and error on the second table cell on id? it seems you miss the dot after id?. Well Itś seem you have repeated agent?.id

Comment: Yes have try this. But its not working

Comment: Check my next answer to see if resolve your issue,

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the `-->` at the end of the first table cell and correct the binding on the second one.

```
<tbody class="text-center">
  <tr *ngFor="let agent of agentlist ;let i = index">
      <td>{{i + 1 + paginationObject?.page * paginationObject?.itemPerPage}}</td>-->
      <td>{{agent?.id}}</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

Also, you need to make sure that `agentlist` has something to iterate. maybe putting a `console.log(agentlist)` and see what it has inside of it in the ts class. If `angelist` is only declared but never defined you will get that error. Initialize `angelist` as an empty array to make sure that have an iterable before defining with the final data.